# Interop between node-jose (js) and jwcrypto (python) using EC keys?

Tags: javascript, python, jwt, jwe

I'm struggling to produce a JWE in jwcrypto equivalent to that in node-jose with the same key. The goal is to produce a key in node-jose and export the pubkey to jwcrypto to encrypt a payload, which will then be consumed by node-jose and decrypted.

My test entirely in node-jose works fine:

```
var jose = require("node-jose")
var keyStore = jose.JWK.createKeyStore()

keyStore.generate('EC', 'P-521').then(function (result) {

    // Use exported key to encrypt something (so we see the same thing jwcrypto does)    
    jose.JWK.asKey(result.toJSON()).then(function(result) {

        jose.JWE.createEncrypt(result).update('this is a test payload').final().then(function (result) {

            jose.JWE.createDecrypt(keyStore).decrypt(result).then(function (result) {

                // Result is good
                console.log(result)
        })
    })

})
```

However, when I do the same in python, node-jose produces a different JWE:

```
    key = jwk.JWK(**json.loads(the_exported_key))

    # This key looks exactly the same as the exported key in node-jose
    print(key.export(private_key=False))

    payload = "this is a test payload"

    header = {
        'alg': 'ECDH-ES',
        'enc': 'A128CBC-HS256',
    }
    my_jwe = jwe.JWE(payload.encode('utf-8'), header)
    my_jwe.add_recipient(key)
```

When node-jose tries to decrypt my_jwe, it fails with "Error: no key found". Strangely (or not, this is my first time using JWEs...), the two encryption results are (see examples below). I think I'm missing how to get jwcrypto to, like node-jose, not require 'header' values, but when I pull those it complains.

node-jose example (junk data):

```
{
    ciphertext: "1e7YX6hNDJWJELhHTNXEOg",
    iv: "oQZZq2smHX8u8MMwoC6NBA",
    protected: "eyJhbGciOi".....(very long string),
    tag: "3NfEqx9f2ivL8QodG5Duaw",
}
```

jwcrypto (junk data):

```
{
    ciphertext: "7ldKnkcsLZUy-SXFRv_HpkWOsb-YUUlNFv-4M5yZhCA",
    iv: "1uErMiK_RWcaPXPCPq12Uw",
    header: {
        alg: "ECDH-ES",
        enc: "A128CBC-HS256",
        epk: {
            crv: "P-521",
            kty: "EC",
            x: different from the exported key, I assume this is expected 'epk', 
            y: different from the exported key, I assume this is expected 'epk',
        },
        kid: "JCU3sWKfirVybFbpy2NPOnq-4-43JiemRZLO5dmPMVo"
    },
    tag: "51AMFyCJld5uPyMFLLl-sw",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The results you got with jwcrypto or node-jose look compliant with the RFC7516.
The only difference is that node-jose set your header in the `protected` member (integrity protected header) whereas jwcrypto set it in the `header` member (per-recipient unprotected header).

My understanding is that node-jose throws an error because it cannot find the public key in the header (`epk` member). It only checks the `protected` member and not other headers (`header` and also `unprotected` members if present) which is not compliant with the [RFC7516 section 2 paragraph 4.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-5.2):

> let the JOSE Header be the union of the members of the JWE Protected Header, the JWE Shared Unprotected Header and the corresponding JWE Per-Recipient Unprotected Header

From my point of view, when a JWE is created for only one recipient, there is no reason to set the `epk` member (as well as the `alg` and `enc` members) in an unprotected header. The presence of those unprotected headers will prevent you from using the JWE Compact Serialization. So the behaviour of jwcrypto should be changed.

I don't know how these two libraries work, however there are two ways to fix that issue:

- Force jwcrypto to use the integrity protected header instead of the unprotected one (**best**).
- Ask node.jose to take into account the other headers (**good** but may take some time)